# How to calculate $ {i}^{i} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We know Euler's formula 
$$e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$$

Let say $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Then we will get $$e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) + i \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
As we can see    $$e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} =  i$$ 
Then we can wright...       $$i^i = i^{e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}}$$  or
$$i^i = (e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}})^i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \approx 0.208$$
As we can see the result is as Real number. It is not an imaginary number!
Did I compute it correctly?
I think that I made little mistake above instead of $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ I should wrote $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} +2\pi k $ ,  $ k\in N\cup {0}$
$$e^{i {(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k})} =  i$$ 
$$i^i = (e^{i (\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k)})^i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\pi k}$$
So...
$$k = 0 \implies e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} \approx 0.208 $$
$$k = 1 \implies e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} - 2\pi} \approx 3.882*10^{-4} $$
$$k = 3 \implies e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} - 6\pi} \approx 1.354*10^{-9} $$

Is it true that: As we can see $ {i}^{i} $ has a lot of answers!?
I mean it has as many answers as many natural number exists!
Are all answers as a real number?

Comment: It's understand that unlike real exponents imaginary  powers have multiple values.  I believe this is true regardless of base.  I believe $2^i$ has infinite many values too.

Comment: The trouble starts at "Then we can wright..."

Answer (score 1):

The mapping $z \mapsto z^\alpha$ is defined by $f_{\alpha}(z) = e^{\alpha\log(z)}$, note that the complex logarithm is defined with $\log(z) = \log |z| + i\arg(z)$

That being said, we can calculate: $i^i = e^{i\log(i)} = e^{i ( \log|i| + i\arg (i)) } = e^{-1\cdot(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)} $.

- There are infinitely many results. This is due to the multivalueness of the $\log , \arg$ functions.
- As you can see, the result is real for all $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: You are right! I made little mistake when I wrote:  $ k\in N\cup {0}$  Thank you!