# problem with the exponential function

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I have a problem :

$ e^i = e^{i*2\pi*1/(2\pi)} = ({e^{i*2\pi}})^{1/(2\pi)} = 1^{1/(2\pi)} = 1$

and this is obviously not true.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: May be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462146/how-to-calculate-ii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property $a^{b/c}= (a^b)^{1/c}$ does not hold for all numbers (not for non-real or negatives. This is because this property defines a composition of functions that in this case cannot be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You assumed that $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$. Not true. Actually, it doesn't even make sense in general.